# Random parse issues

Tags: ios, xcode, parsing

My code was working fine then all of a sudden i got these 4 random parse issues...
Can anyone help me out with whats happened?

Image below shows the issues.

http://postimage.org/image/qu0gzsoe3/

Code is also below

```
    #import "ComputingProjectFirstViewController.h"

@interface ComputingProjectFirstViewController()



@end

@implementation ComputingProjectFirstViewController

@synthesize imageview = HomeImage;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{

    NSAssert(self.imageview, @"self.imageView is nil. Check your IBOutlet connections");

    imageArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                  [UIImage imageNamed:@"wide awake 0.jpg"],
                  [UIImage imageNamed:@"wide awake 1.jpg"],
                  [UIImage imageNamed:@"wide awake 2.jpg"],
                  [UIImage imageNamed:@"wide awake 3.jpg"],
                  [UIImage imageNamed:@"wide awake 4.jpg"],
                  [UIImage imageNamed:@"wide awake 5.jpg"],
                  [UIImage imageNamed:@"wide awake 6.jpg"],
                  nil];
                self.imageview.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
                  self.imageview.clipsToBounds = YES;

    int count = [imageArray count];
    for (int i = 0; i <count-1 ; i++)
    {
        UIImage *currentImage = [imageArray objectAtIndex: i];
        UIImage *nextImage = [imageArray objectAtIndex: i +1];
        self.imageview.image = [imageArray objectAtIndex: i];
        [self.view addSubview:self.imageview];
        CABasicAnimation *crossFade = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"contents"];
        crossFade.duration = 5.0;
        crossFade.fromValue = (__bridge id)(currentImage.CGImage);
        crossFade.toValue = (__bridge id)(nextImage.CGImage);
        [self.imageview.layer addAnimation:crossFade forKey:@"animateContents"];
        self.imageview.image = nextImage;

    };
```

.h file:

```
 #import <UIKit/UIKit.h> 
 #import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>
 #import <MessageUI/MessageUI.h>


 @interface ComputingProjectFirstViewController :       UIViewController<MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate>{
UIImageView* HomeImage;
NSArray *imageArray;


@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIImageView* imageview;



@end
```

Comment: The problem is a syntax error in the header file that you include. Can you include the contents of "ComputingProjectFirstViewController.h"

Comment: You're missing your closing parenthesis in your header after imageArray.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If thats all you have for `viewDidLoad` your missing a extra `}` at the end your `viewDidLoad` method, also remove your `;` at the end of your for loop. Should be like this

```
#import "ComputingProjectFirstViewController.h"

@interface ComputingProjectFirstViewController()



@end

@implementation ComputingProjectFirstViewController

@synthesize imageview = HomeImage;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{

    NSAssert(self.imageview, @"self.imageView is nil. Check your IBOutlet connections");

    imageArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                 [UIImage imageNamed:@"wide awake 0.jpg"],
                 [UIImage imageNamed:@"wide awake 1.jpg"],
                 [UIImage imageNamed:@"wide awake 2.jpg"],
                 [UIImage imageNamed:@"wide awake 3.jpg"],
                 [UIImage imageNamed:@"wide awake 4.jpg"],
                 [UIImage imageNamed:@"wide awake 5.jpg"],
                 [UIImage imageNamed:@"wide awake 6.jpg"],
                 nil];
                 self.imageview.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
                 self.imageview.clipsToBounds = YES;

    int count = [imageArray count];
    for (int i = 0; i <count-1 ; i++)
    {
        UIImage *currentImage = [imageArray objectAtIndex: i];
        UIImage *nextImage = [imageArray objectAtIndex: i +1];
        self.imageview.image = [imageArray objectAtIndex: i];
        [self.view addSubview:self.imageview];
        CABasicAnimation *crossFade = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"contents"];
        crossFade.duration = 5.0;
        crossFade.fromValue = (__bridge id)(currentImage.CGImage);
        crossFade.toValue = (__bridge id)(nextImage.CGImage);
        [self.imageview.layer addAnimation:crossFade forKey:@"animateContents"];
        self.imageview.image = nextImage;

    }
}
```

Also in your header you are missing a  `}` should look like this :

```
 #import <UIKit/UIKit.h> 
 #import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>
 #import <MessageUI/MessageUI.h>


 @interface ComputingProjectFirstViewController : UIViewController<MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate>{
    UIImageView* HomeImage;
    NSArray *imageArray;
 }

 @property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIImageView* imageview;



 @end
```